# Como mudar a cor de um select ao selecionar uma opção

Tags: css, html5, css3, sass

Tenho um select e estou tentando mudar a cor do mesmo ao selecionar uma opção (para o exemplo estou mudando a cor para `red`). Usando alguns atributos como `hover`, `focus`, `active` e `checked` eu até consigo fazer o que eu quero. O problema é que quando o select perde o focus ele retorna a sua cor original.

Quero que o select permaneça com a cor cinza enquanto não for selecionado e após selecionado que a cor `red` seja aplicada. Mesmo que ele perca o foco depois.

```css
select {
  color: gray;
}

select:hover,
select:focus,
select:active,
select:checked {
  color: red;
}

select option {
  color: #333;
}

option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="estado" name="estado">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
            <option value="AC">AC</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option>
            <option value="AM">AM</option>
            <option value="AP">AP</option>
            <option value="BA">BA</option>
            <option value="CE">CE</option>
            <option value="DF">DF</option>
            <option value="ES">ES</option>
            <option value="GO">GO</option>
            <option value="MA">MA</option>
            <option value="MG">MG</option>
            <option value="MS">MS</option>
            <option value="MT">MT</option>
            <option value="PA">PA</option>
            <option value="PB">PB</option>
            <option value="PE">PE</option>
            <option value="PI">PI</option>
            <option value="PR">PR</option>
            <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
            <option value="RN">RN</option>
            <option value="RO">RO</option>
            <option value="RR">RR</option>
            <option value="RS">RS</option>
            <option value="SP">SP</option>
            <option value="SC">SC</option>
            <option value="SE">SE</option>
            <option value="TO">TO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nunca vi um método por `css` não cara. Já pensou em usar `js`?

Comment: Oi @LeonardoRodrigues! com js seria fácil! mas aqui só usamos para deixar a pagina dinânica ou para animações mais complexas! de resto toda a estilização fazemos usando apenas css e sass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando o [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) for suportado nos navegadores poderia utilizar, *acredito que iria funcionar*:

```
select:has(option[value=""]) {
  color: red;
}
```

Entretanto, até o momento **nenhum navegador suporta** e talvez isto nem saia do papel.

---

Uma opção seria criar uma longa transação/animação, assim prevenindo que a cor volte para o estado normal.

> **/!\ Isso é uma gambiarra!**

Dessa forma o `select` irá demorar 2147483647 segundos para voltar ao estado normal, que é `gray`, isso funciona usando o `transition: color 0s 2147483647s;`.

Enquanto isso quando houver o `hover`, por exemplo, a cor seria modificada imediatamente, graças ao `transition:0s;`.

Então isso atende a pergunta de "Quero que o select permaneça com a cor red após a seleção de uma opção. Mesmo que ele perca o foco depois.", *mas o uso de JQuery, como já foi respondido, seria o ideal.*

```css
select {
  color: gray;
  transition: color 0s 2147483647s;
}

select:hover,
select:focus,
select:active,
select:focus {
  color: red;
  transition:0s;
}

select option {
  color: #333;
}

option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="estado" name="estado">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 só pelo aviso de atenção isso é uma gambiarra

Comment: Poxa @Inkeliz! As vezes e somente as vezes precisamos recorrer a ganbiarras para resolver um problema ou outro! kkk! Mas a sua solução me serviu muito bem! o importante é q irá funcionar da forma esperada! valeu! :)

Answer (score 5):

Um script jQuery bem simples resolve!

O que precisa fazer é mudar o css quando o elemento é selecionado.

```
$('#estado').change(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpjxxhek/)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Amanda Lima! Mas aqui a parti de estilização trabalhamos apenas com css e sass. Usamos o javascript e jQuery apenas para animações mais complexa. De qualquer forma valeu! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
        <select id="estado" class="color_gray" name="estado">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="AC">AC</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="AP">AP</option>
        <option value="BA">BA</option>
        <option value="CE">CE</option>
        <option value="DF">DF</option>
        <option value="ES">ES</option>
        <option value="GO">GO</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="MG">MG</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
        <option value="MT">MT</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="PB">PB</option>
        <option value="PE">PE</option>
        <option value="PI">PI</option>
        <option value="PR">PR</option>
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="RO">RO</option>
        <option value="RR">RR</option>
        <option value="RS">RS</option>
        <option value="SP">SP</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="SE">SE</option>
        <option value="TO">TO</option>
        </select>
```

css
             .color_red 
             {
                 color: red;
             }
            .color_gray
             {
                color: gray;
             }

Js

```
       $( "select" )
        .change(function () {

            var $SL = $('#estado');
            $SL.addClass('color_red');
            $SL.removeClass('color_gray');

           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas troque a cor do `select` em:

```
select {
    color: gray;
}
```

PARA

```
select {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Acho que ele deseja que a cor se mantenha `gray` até que o usuário modifique, tirando da opção padrão.

Comment: @Inkeliz "Quero que o select permaneça com a cor red após a seleção de uma opção. Mesmo que ele perca o foco depois."

Comment: Dessa forma que apresentou ele terá a cor red mesmo antes de perder o foco, não somente durante e depois.

Comment: é isso mesmo @Inkeliz! o select inicia com a cor gray e só muda para red após uma seleção! a solução do @Inkeliz me serviu muito bem! :